# How to write qcircuit code for the following figure

Tags: circuits, qcircuit

[image]

I have been trying to write code for the following figure using the `qcircuit` environment. But did not succeed. Kindly help me in writing its code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far!

Comment: You will find that people are much more likely to help if you make a real attempt at solving the problem yourself. You should provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE), which should compile on its own, even if it doesn't produce the result you want. In this case, there should be an attempt at using the `\targ` and `\ctrl` commands in the `Qcircuit` package.

Answer (score 3):

The `qcircuit` code to produce the gate is

```
\Qcircuit @C=2.5em @R=2.5em{& \ctrl{1} & \qw \\& \targ & \qw}
```

You can adjust the `2.5em` lengths to change the size of the gate. To vertically center the gate in an array or table, you must enclose the above code in an array or table of its own. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 & Gate notation & Matrix representation\\[2ex]
\begin{tabular}{c}\emph{Controlled-NOT}\\gate\end{tabular} & 
\begin{tabular}{c}\Qcircuit @C=2.5em @R=2.5em{& \ctrl{1} & \qw \\& \targ & \qw} \end{tabular} &
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]